# vi commandline, goto line and column

Tags: vim, cursor

I have been mixing the use of `emacs` and `vi` (`vim`) for a long time. Each of them has its advantage. I parse error output from a compilation like process and get a line and column number but I can only use `emacs` to directly go to a line and column:

```
emacs +15:25 myfile.xml
```

with `vi` I only have the line number (according to the man page)

```
vi +15 myfile.xml
```

There is an option to go position cursor on a pattern (`vi +/pattern myfile.xml`) which i never got to work. But that would not help me as the pattern is not always the first occurrence in the file.

How can I start `vi` so it goes to column 25 on line 15 of my file? Can I do something with `-c` option?

Comment: Since you tagged vim, have you considered the `quickfix` system, which runs the compiler from within vim, parses the error output, populates a list of errors (navigate with `:cp`, `:cn`, `:cl` commands), and positions your cursor at the first one?

Comment: If you open a file in vi, and type `:15` it will jump to line 15.. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 20):

You can use:

```
vi '+normal 15G25|'  myfile.xml
```

Comment: explanation: most commands (ie, most letter) in vi can be preceded by a number (or range) to change its default behaviour or to repeat it (or apply it on a specific range). Inside vi, in command mode, you can do `15G` to go to line 15 and `25|` to go to col 25. And Christa shows how to do the same from the command-line.

Answer (score 10):

With the [file-line plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184), you can simply append line and column to the file name, both when invoking Vim and inside with commands like `:edit`:

```
vim myfile.xml:15:25
```

Comment: Good to know this exist, but I think I will use a answer that doesn't require extra plugin

Comment: @Dominique You can also `vim myfile.xml +15` for row without a plugin, but not column as far as I know

Answer (score 6):

just for fun there is `-c 'normal 14j24l'` which will put you on line 15 character 25

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about the `-c` option, but you should be able to do:

```
vi '+cal cursor(15,25)' myfile.xml
```

(make sure you quote because of the parenthesis `()` )

Comment: `cursor()` uses byte index for the column, but it's usually a character count.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Does that really matter? Text is UTF-8.

Comment: It matters for non-ASCII characters, which are represented by more than one byte. Also, a Tab and control characters usually occupy more than one display column.

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting:

```
-c command
```

Run the given ex command upon startup. ***Only one -c option is permitted for vi***; Vim accepts up to 10. An older form of this option, `+command`, is still supported.

The `+command` has the same single `ex command` limitation when using `vi`.

The `+/pattern` is also limited to one command with `vi`.

( taken from [vim and ex editor](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/excerpts/9780596529833/the-vi-ex-and-vim-editors.html) )

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code to your vimrc, When you comeback to your file, vim back automatically to old position:

```
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```